# Angular2 - clear multiple input fields created with a ngFor loop

Tags: angular

Here is a simplified version of what I have ...

The component:

```
...
ngOnInit() {

    items = [
      {
          "image": "/img1.jpg",
          "answer" : "item1"
      },
      {
          "image": "/img2.jpg",
          "answer" : "item2"
      },
      {
          "image": "/img3.jpg",
          "answer" : "item3"
      },
    ]

}

verify(event:any, i) {
    ...checking if the input matches its answer. No problem here.
}
```

The html template:

```
<template ngFor let-item let-i="index" [ngForOf]="items">
    <li>
       <div style="background: url('{{item.image}}')"></div>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.input" (keyup)="verify($event, i)">
    </li>
</template>

<button type="button" (click)="clearFields()"></button>
```

How can the clearFields() function work? I don't want to use re-routing since there can be other similar components on the same page.

Comment: what do you mean by re-routing ?

Comment: I mean by not navigating away and back to the page.

Comment: it shouldn't. but you can add `type="button"` on your button

Comment: thanks. done. but the button here is just an example to show that I need a clearFields() function to clear all of the component's input fields.

Comment: can you just make a function like that:
`clearFields() {
    for (let item of this.items) {
      item.input = "";
    }
  }
` ?

Comment: I see. Can't you just re-assign the items that doesn't have any input ?

Comment: Thanks Doron. It did the trick. My junior javascript skills are transpiring. You can post it as an answer if you like and will accept the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function like that:

```
clearFields() { 
  for (let item of this.items) { 
    item.input = ""; 
  } 
}
```